# Regex string split into an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I need to split a string following several rules, however, I'm not very experienced with regex or PHP arrays.
So the string is this:

```
A N K U N F T   11.08.15
*** N ***
11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  18:40  F882129  dsdsaidsaia  F882129  xxxyxyagydaysd
```

And i need to get this in the string to an array:

```
date1 ->  11.08.15

date2-> 18.08.15

fnr1 -> X3 2830

h1 - > 17:50

fnr2 -> X3 2830

h2 -> 18:40

n1 -> dsdsaidsaia

n2 -> xxxyxyagydaysd
```

I have done the following at regex101:

for fnr:

```
(\w{2}\s\d{4})
```

for date:

```
(\n\s\d{2}\W\d{2}\W\d{2})
```

for h:

```
(\s{2}\d{2}\:\d{2}\n)
```

However, I don't know how to differentiate date1 from date2, fnr1 from fnr2 and h1 from.

And I'v tried this in php for the dates and it doesnt output the dates I want:

```
$re = "/(\n\s\d{2}\W\d{2}\W\d{2})/"; 
$str = "";//the string
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is consistent about this data? Kinda looks like tab delimited data... `\t` is a tab `\h` is a horizontal space.

Comment: This is not a code writing server. YOU show what you've gotten working so far, we'll (maybe) try help fixing it.

Comment: Put that in your question and it might be removed from hold. I can answer this but he hold is stopping me

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you want:

```
^((?:\d{2}\.?){3}).*?(\w{2}\s\d{4}).*?(\d{2}:\d{2})(?:.*?(\b[a-z]+\b).*?(\b[a-z]+\b))?$
```

It separates everything on each line into the various capture groups. Let me know if you have problems.

Note: make sure to have flags `gm` on so that `^` and `$` make each line start and end; not the entire string.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uA1dJ2/1)

Comment: @MiguelSousa you can't honestly expect me to read that in a comment, do you? Please just edit your question and let me know you've edited it.

Comment: @MiguelSousa `preg_match` is not a global match. `preg_match_all` is. It now gives the desired result.

Comment: @MiguelSousa did that answer your question?